# Runtime error when using N-1 in limit clause of select query when N=0

Tags: mysql, runtime-error

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT N-1,1
);
END
```

this query gives exception when M=0 as it becomes -1 however when I write it like

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE M INT;
SET M=N-1;
  RETURN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT M,1
);
END
```

Please explain the difference between the two statements. When I set M= N-1 , m will also be negative when N=0 it gives following exception

```
Line 6: SyntaxError: near '-1,1
);
END'
```

Comment: You may want to make sure `N > 0` within the function.

Comment: @ Ja͢ck but in the second function also I am not checking for >0 but it is working fine

Comment: You can't use expressions for the `LIMIT` arguments, hence the syntax error.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this helps. But this looks like a problem from Leet Code (https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary). I ran the below and it worked for me.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE M INT;
SET M=N-1;
RETURN (
   select distinct
       Salary
   from 
       Employee
   Order by 1 desc
   limit M, 1

   );
   END
```

And here's the submission result:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'm arriving late on this, but I struggled with this problem too. Spent hours debugging this. You could always check for this condition in the `where` clause. Check the query below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE M INT;
SET M = -1;
 RETURN (
    select distinct salary from employee where M > 0 order by salary desc limit M,1
 );
END
```

The parameters in limit are confusing as well. In some cases `offset` is not supported. There's a simple example for this.

```
limit a,b;
```

We can read the above as

> start from a and stop after b number of entries.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to group the salaries.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  set N = N - 1;
  RETURN (
      select salary from Employee group by salary order by salary desc limit 1 offset N
  );
END
```

So if you have two salaries of 100 and you are looking for 2nd highest, the answer should be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

My answer Thanks for @George Hayward

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    set N = N-1;

  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
    IFNULL(
      (SELECT DISTINCT Salary
       FROM Employee
       ORDER BY Salary DESC
        LIMIT N,1),
    NULL)
  );
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  SET N = N-1;
    RETURN (
        SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM Employee 
        ORDER BY salary DESC 
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET N);
END;
```